# sass files, compile and seperate theme-color files with gulp

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I have a folder structure like this:

```
|- assets
     |- sass
          global.scss
          _mixin.scss
          _body.scss
          _header.scss
          _footer.scss
          |- themes
               blue.scss
               base.scss
               dark.scss
```

I want to compile my sass files and get this css structure out of it (the most important is that I want separate css files for my color):

```
|- assets
     |- cdd
          global.css
          |- themes
               blue.css
               base.css
               dark.css
```

I'm using this gulpfile.js file to compile this

```
'use strict';

var gulp        = require('gulp'),
concat      = require('gulp-concat'),
plumber     = require('gulp-plumber'),
sass        = require('gulp-sass');

// Gulp plumber error handler
function errorLog(error) {
   console.error.bind(error);
   this.emit('end');
}

// Compile Sass files into CSS
gulp.task('sass', function () {
return gulp.src('./assets/sass/**/*.scss')
            // Sass - Compile Sass files into CSS
            .pipe(sass({
                outputStyle: 'expanded',
                includePaths: ['./assets/sass/']
            }))
      .on('error', errorLog)
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/css'))
 });

gulp.task('default', ['sass']);
```

it is not making separate color file for me, and the color theme files are appended in the end of the global.css file

Comment: You can try to exclude your themes from `gulp.src` as `return gulp.src(['./assets/sass/**/*.scss', '!./assets/sass/themes/*.scss])`. You also need a separately task to build your themes.

Comment: @andorx Thanks for your point;)
does the import command in sass files have importance?

Comment: Sure, you have to remove any `@import` themes from your `global.scss` file. If there is any mixins, vars that are required in your themes, you should create new file in your themes folder that contains these mixins and import it to every single theme files.

Answer (score 3):

The way I created different themes for a project was to split my scss like so;

```
|- scss
|- |- core
|- |- |- _all-my-scss-files-and-folders.scss
|- |- |- _config.scss 
|- |- |- core.scss
|- |- themes
|- |- |- blue.scss
|- |- |- yellow.scss
|- |- |- pink.scss
```

Within `_config.scss` you set your default colour scheme

```
$colour-primary-main: #FFF !default;
$colour-primary-secondary: #EEE !default;
$colour-primary-tetiary: #E0E0E0 !default;
$colour-primary-quaternary: #R4R4R4 !default;
```

Within your themes scss files you overwrite your variables and then `@import` your partials

```
$colour-primary-main: #333;
$colour-primary-secondary: #000;
$colour-primary-tetiary: #444;
$colour-primary-quaternary: #FEFEFE;

@import '../core/config';
etc
```

You then will need to set up a new gulp task that compiles your theme SCSS files

```
gulp.task('sass-theme', function () {
  return gulp.src('assets/sass/theme/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({
      outputStyle: 'expanded',
    }))
    .on('error', errorLog)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/css'))
});
```

You also will need to ignore the new themes folder on your default scss task

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src([
      'assets/sass/**/*.scss',
      '!assets/sass/themes/*.scss';
    ])
    .pipe(sass({
      outputStyle: 'expanded',
    }))
    .on('error', errorLog)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/css'))
 });
```

Comment: Your approach is good for a file with all the variables, but i think Ebrahim want a different file for each color theme, so remove the ! ignore line,

And then be carefull with the partials _file.scss  and the main files without the underscore.

Comment: @HéctorLeón Not fully sure what your saying, but this will work even if you don't have a _config.scss file. As long as you have used variables you will be able to overwrite them. quote - "but i think Ebrahim want a different file for each color theme" - Thats what my second "sass-theme" task does?

Comment: Sorry if i didn't explain correctly 
Just saying you used 
|- |- |- _blue.scss
|- |- |- _yellow.scss
|- |- |- _pink.scss

_ underscore in sass is used for partials,  they would be compiled into a one single file.
just remove it because he want a css file for each scss ones right ?  but the task works sweet :D

Comment: @HéctorLeón Ah yeah! Thanks for that!